# Unescape apostrophe (&#39;) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm trying to unescape a HTML-escaped apostrophe (`"&#39;"`) in JavaScript, but the following doesn't seem to work on a devtools console line:

```
unescape('&#39;');
```

The output is simply:

```
"&#39;"
```

It doesn't work in Underscore's unescape either:

```
_.unescape('&#39;')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `unescape` is a poorly-named (and deprecated) function that does **URL** decoding, not HTML decoding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`unescape` has nothing to do with HTML character entities. It's an old, deprecated function for decoding text encoded with `escape`, which is an old, deprecated function for encoding text in a way that is unlikely to be useful in the modern world. :-)

If you need to turn that HTML into plain text, the easiest way is via an element:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "&#39;";
alert(div.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/adodef/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/adodef/1/edit)

Note that the above relies on the fact that there are no elements defined in your HTML text, so it knows there is exactly one child node of `div`, which is a text node.

For more complicated use cases, you might use `div.innerText` (if it has one) or `div.textContent`:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "&#39;";
alert(div.innerText || div.textContent || "");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/adodef/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/adodef/2/edit)

Answer (score 10):

By using `createElement` like in T.J.'s answer, you open yourself up to XSS attacks.

[`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) is a [much safer way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37554728/5374560) to correctly unescape HTML entities (including `&#39;`)

```js
function unescape(string) {
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(string,'text/html').querySelector('html').textContent;
}

console.log(unescape('&#39;'));
```

You can use the function above with a string from any source, and the string won't be able to modify your page or steal data by including JavaScript.