# Can a "new DOMParser.parseFromString" be safer than "createElement"?

Tags: javascript, xss

I create a script for try remove insecure content (I'm using it for browser extensions):

```js
var str = "<strong>Hello</strong> mundo <script src="http://site/badscript.js"></script>";
CreateDOM(str);

function RemoveAttrs(target)
{
    var attrs = target.attributes, currentAttr;
    var validAttrs = [ "href", "class", "id", "target" ];

    for (var i = attrs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentAttr = attrs[i].name;

        if (attrs[i].specified && validAttrs.indexOf(currentAttr) === -1) {
            target.removeAttribute(currentAttr);
        }

        if (
            currentAttr === "href" &&
            /^(#|javascript[:])/gi.test(target.getAttribute("href"))
        ) {
            target.parentNode.removeChild(currentAttr);
        }
    }
}

function RemoveEls(target)
{
    var current;

    //Remove elements insecure (blacklist)
    var list = target.querySelectorAll("script,link,...");

    for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        current = list[i];
        current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
    }

    //Remove insecure attributes (whitelist)
    list = target.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        RemoveAttrs(list[i]);
    }

    return target;
}

function CreateDOM(MinhaString)
{
     var tmpDom = document.createElement("div");
     tmpDom.innerHTML = MinhaString;

     tmpDom = RemoveEls(tmpDom);

     //Inject in container
     document.getElementById("container").appendChild(tmpDom);
}
```

I'm using this script in an addon I created for opera and Google Chorme, however the site moderator ("addons.opera.com") said to me this:

> Your cleanDomString method is not safe, please replace:
>   tmpDom.innerHTML = data; with: var tmpDom = (new
>   DOMParser).parseFromString(data, "text/html").body;
>
> and remove: var tmpDom = document.createElement("div");
>
> or use:
>   https://github.com/operatester/safeResponse/blob/1.1/safeResponse.js
>
> dmichnowicz; May 30, 2016 8:46:57 AM UTC

The code looks like this:

```js
var str = "<strong>Hello</strong> mundo <script src="http://site/badscript.js"></script>";
CreateDOM(str);

function RemoveAttrs(target)
{
    var attrs = target.attributes, currentAttr;
    var validAttrs = [ "href", "class", "id", "target" ];

    for (var i = attrs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentAttr = attrs[i].name;

        if (attrs[i].specified && validAttrs.indexOf(currentAttr) === -1) {
            target.removeAttribute(currentAttr);
        }

        if (
            currentAttr === "href" &&
            /^(#|javascript[:])/gi.test(target.getAttribute("href"))
        ) {
            target.parentNode.removeChild(currentAttr);
        }
    }
}

function RemoveEls(target)
{
    var current;

    //Remove elements insecure (blacklist)
    var list = target.querySelectorAll("script,link,...");

    for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        current = list[i];
        current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
    }

    //Remove insecure attributes (whitelist)
    list = target.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        RemoveAttrs(list[i]);
    }

    return target;
}

function CreateDOM(MyString)
{
     var tmpDom = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(MyString, "text/html").body;

     tmpDom = RemoveEls(tmpDom);

     //Inject in container
     document.getElementById("container").appendChild(tmpDom);
}
```

I made the change, but I would like to understand what it became safer my code. For me they both seem to do the same thing.

What are the differences (terms of their safety)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Effectively, your current code is not safe. `innerHTML` doesn't run scripts in created `<script>` elements, but it does run event handler content attributes.

```js
function createDOM(str) {
  document.createElement("div").innerHTML = str;
}
createDOM('<img src="//" onerror="console.log(\'You are pwned!\')" />');
```

```js
function createDOM(str) {
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
}
createDOM('<img src="//" onerror="console.log(\'You are safe\')" />');
```

However, note that `DOMParser` provides safety if you only want to manipulate the DOM elements from an untrusted HTML string. It's like a sandbox. But if then you get these elements and append it in the current document, they will still be able to run JS.

```js
function createDOM(str) {
  document.body.appendChild(new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").body);
}
createDOM('<img src="//" onerror="console.log(\'You are pwned!\')" />');
```

If you really need something like this, I would use a small whitelist of allowed elements and attributes, and get rid of everything else.

Comment: Thanks, got it! But what about `RemoveAttrs()` function?

Comment: You are not attaching the parsed document into the DOM in the second snippet. I don't think DOMParser will guard against scripts.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `RemoveAttrs` does not seem to parse untrusted strings, so it seems safe.

Comment: Got it, the `onerror` was executed even without adding to the `document.body`. That's it?

Comment: @kennytm Ah, OK, now I see what you meant. I didn't look at the code in the question properly. I will clarify.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Yes, that was the problem. But if you append it to the current document, the JS will run even if you used `DOMParser`

Comment: Wonder how complicated it would be to parse HTML with `parseFromString` and then loop over all element and recreate everything with `createElement` and `setAttribute` and so on... this would be a complex but helpful tool wonder if someone made something like this already?