# Javascript DOM Document Query on Variable

Tags: javascript, dom

So let's say I have a WYSIWYG (Tiny MCE in my case) and I take some input.
I want to look at that input and extract any base64 images and then send those somewhere to be converted to URL's in an AWS bucket.
I can do the last bit but I'm stuck with the middle part which is to extract the elements from a variable.

This is what I am trying that does not work ["TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined"]

```
let dombody = document.createElement("div").append(mcebody);
let imglist = dombody.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions in advance.  Perhaps this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

`.append` [has no return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append), so `dombody` is `undefined`, so an error is thrown when you try to call a method on it.

Assign the `dombody` in an earlier statement instead (and remember to [use `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) instead of `let` when possible):

```
const dombody = document.createElement("div");
dombody.append(mcebody);
const imglist = dombody.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Comment: Wow that was fast!

Comment: Thankyou!

I just realised I could do this:

```let dombody = document.createElement("div");
dombody.innerHTML = mcebody;
let imglist = dombody.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Comment: But I prefer your one :) Thanks!

Comment: To avoid unwanted scripts from running, it would be safer to use `.append` (or, even better, `DOMParser`); `.innerHTML` can allow for arbitrary code execution. It's *probably* not an issue, but it *might* be, so avoiding it would be a good habit to get into.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `DOMParser.parseFromString()` may be subject to XSS vulnerabilities too. See [this article](https://web.dev/trusted-types/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37554623/1244884)

Comment: @customcommander That sounds interesting, I'd really like to know how if it's true - but the SO link shows that DOMParser is only an issue if the created element then gets appended to the document (which would of course be unsafe), and I don't see anything in the web.dev link showing how `DOMParser` alone is potentially unsafe. Do you have an example?

Comment: I was only pointing out that `DOMParser.parseFromString` isn't 100% safe. The web.dev link only mentions all the sinks that developers should pay attention to because of their XSS vulnerabilities.