# Rendering HTML as... HTML? In Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

So I have what should be a simple problem: I want to render some HTML as HTML and not as a string. My code takes a list from a textarea, then alphabetizes it, then spits it out in `<span>` tags. But I want the HTML to actually render and not literally display "`<span>Bar</span><span>Foo</span>`".

I'm trying DOMParser, which seems like it should be the answer, but somehow I'm missing a step.

```
const mwInput = document.querySelector('.mw__input');
const mwOutput = document.querySelector('.mw__output');

var stringToHTML = function(str) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var theParsed = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  return theParsed.body;
}

document.querySelector('#alphabetize').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var theText = mwInput.value;
  theText = mwInput.value.split('\n').sort();
  var theOutput = '';

  theText.map(
    function(item, i) {
      theOutput += '<span>' + item + '</span>';
    }
  );

  mwOutput.innerHTML = stringToHTML(theOutput).innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: This is what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special. Just `myOutput.innerHTML = theOutput;`

Comment: You don't actually need any library to achieve that, simply setting the innerHTML to the string representing the html should be fine. If it doesn't work try to create a codepen so that we can see the actual problem.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/413vtnwj/3/

Comment: Related question for the technique: [Can a “new DOMParser.parseFromString” be safer than “createElement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37554623/5217142)

Comment: You're all right. The problem was that .mw__output was a textarea, which I didn't realize made a difference until I saw the comments!