# Passing params through URL - Single quotes become &#39;

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I'm working with a ASP.NET project. We are passing params through the url and every time a single quote is passed the url changes all single quotes to %27 and the actual value read in through the javascript changes all single quotes to &#39;

Can someone tell me how I can maintain the single quotes as our parameters need to match the exact values. This is my code.

```
public class Model
{
   public string example {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult Index(string example)
{
   var model = new Model();
   model.example = example;
   return View(model);
}

Index.cshtml at the bottom ---------------------

<script type="text/javascript">
   var example = "@Model.example";
   Main();
</script>

Javascript -----------------

console.log(example);
```

Examples: [www.example.com?example=Turtle's_Are_Cool](http://www.example.com?example=Turtle%27s_Are_Cool)
Changes the url instantly to => [www.example.com?example=Turtle\%27s_Are_Cool](http://www.example.com?example=Turtle%5C%27s_Are_Cool) and the JavaScript outputs Turtle&#39s_Are_Cool

Comment: You should check this similar issue [ASP.NET single quotes are converted to &#39;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013912/asp-net-single-quotes-are-converted-to-39)

Comment: In the C# debugger, go to the `Immediate Window` and type in `?example.` What **exactly** is shown as the result. Also show us the _exact_ source generated (View Source in the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it on the server side you can use
Server.URLEncode("Turtle's_Are_Cool"))

If you want to manage the same on client-side you can replace ' with '

example = example.replace(/'/g, "\'");

But if you have got a single quote coming from server-side and you want to convert it at client-side then the easiest way is to use HTML element as shown in the below question

[Unescape apostrophe (&#39;) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106164/unescape-apostrophe-39-in-javascript)

Comment: This worked in some sense, it made it so the ' is now replaced with %27 instead of &#39, but the client side still struggles with this representation

Comment: In that case, on client-side simply use 
unescape('%27') //This should give you single quote